# Get Permanent Authorization Code for Salesforce API

Tags: oauth, authorization

I am new to Salesforce integration.I have a web application and want to post user data to SalesForce account.The examples available for this purpose required SalesForce login when try to get Authorization Code using oAuth.This is not possible because when User post data on Application he don't have access to SalesForce account.Is there any way that I get permanent Authorization code.

Comment: If client does not have access to salesforce account where will you post the data? Could you frame your question with clear description

Comment: I have rephrase the question

Comment: Use oAuth with JWT as the referenced answer mentions, plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot get a permanent access token into Salesforce, and no, you cannot authenticate to Salesforce without a user account.*

Some applications do use a generic Integration User account in a Salesforce org, but you must have an account. The details and best practices depend on the architecture and use case of our application.

To establish a persistent connection into Salesforce, your application should execute an OAuth flow that provides a refresh token, such as the [Web Server flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm). Your application can use the refresh token to acquire new access tokens indefinitely, or until access is revoked.

* It is possible to use webhook-style authentication on Salesforce but requires on-platform development and has complex security implications that require expertise in the Salesforce security model.

Comment: Can you help me with any tutorial link for webhook-style authentication on Salesforce

Comment: You'll find examples if you search SFSE. As I said, you have to build functionality on Salesforce in Apex to do that, meaning you must be working with a Salesforce developer.

Comment: Thanks David..Can you tell me from where I can check all the Field name that can be used in creating Account and Opportunity

Comment: Please open a separate question if you have a new issue. But you will find what you need if you search for "<sObject name> Field Reference".